# How should I handle NaN values in a Finance DF?

Tags: python, dataframe, nan, missing-data, finance

I am a beginner in Machine Learning, my point is..how should i encode the column "OECDSTInterbkRate"? I don't know how to replace the missing values and especially with what. Should I just delete them? Or replace them with the mean / median of the values?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to this issue.

- The simplest: if you have huge amount of data - drop NaNs.
- Replace the NaNs with mean/median/etc of the whole non-NaN dataset or the dataset grouped by one or several columns. E.g. for you dataset you can fill the Australia NaNs with a mean for Australian non-NaNs. And the same for other countries.
- A common approach is to create another indicator column after the imputation of NaNs which keeps the indices where the missing data was replaced with a value. This column then is taken as yet another input to your ML algorithm.
- Take a look at the docs (assuming you work with Pandas) - the developers of the library have already created some tools for the missing data: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific answer to your question, it's a general problem in statistics which is called "imputation". Depending on the application the answer could be many things.

There are few alternatives that comes to mind first to solve your problem, but don't forget that "no data" is  almost always better than "bad/wrong data". **If you have more than enough rows without the rows with NaNs, you may simply drop them.** Otherwise you can consider the following:

1. Can you mathematically calculate the column that you need by the other columns that you already have in your dataset? If so, you have your answer.
2. Check the correlation of the particular column by using it's non-missing valued rows with the other columns and see if they are highly correlated. If so, you might just as well try dropping the whole column(might not be always a good idea but it's generally a good idea).
3. Can you create an estimator(such as a regression model) to predict the missing values by learning the pattern using the values that you already have and by using the other columns with a really good accuracy? Well you might have an answer (need benchmarking with the following). Please keep in mind that this is a very risky operation that could give bad estimations and decrease the performance of your overall model. Try this only if your estimations are really good!
4. Is it a regression problem? Using the statistical mean could be a good idea.
5. Is it a classification problem? Using median could be a good idea.
6. In some cases using mode might also be a good idea depending on the distribution.

I suggest that you try all the things out and see which one works better because there's really not a concrete answer to your problem. You can create a machine learning model without using the column and use it's performance as a baseline, and carry out a performance(accuracy) benchmarking for all the steps compared to the baseline.

**Note:** I am just a graduate student with some insights, please comment out if anything I said is not correct!